# Auto-calculating lightning datatable columns based on input received

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-datatable

We have a lightning data table built in LWC, which has 2 columns - start date and end date.[image]
Start Date is going to be the first date of any month and the End Date would be the last date of the same month. However, we expect that as soon as the first start date has been entered manually, the rest of the start and end dates be calculated automatically in the same fashion. And the calculation should happen for next 12 months. Any inputs on how this date calculation should be done and mapped to the data table columns?
The values in the data table are later being stored in the database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking or what you've tried already. Please [edit] your question and add some more of that detail so that we can help.

Comment: The way the datatable works when you enable inline editing is that you need to press "save" after the editing cells. This will be clunky if you do it this way. Perhaps the best way is a separate "initial start date" field that you could enter a date in, triggering all the data to be generated for the datatable.